# Add jdatepicker in jpanel

Tags: java, swing, datepicker, jpanel

I am trying to add jdatepicker in jpanel, this jpanel is called inside jframe, the problem is that if I try to add jdatepicker directly into jpanel it is not displayed, until some event is performed.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933567/add-this-jdatepicker-in-jpanel-instead-jframe-in-java) solution, but this was of no help. When I use this it also open one more window with no data.

and other method I am using is -

Class MainApp which is using frame

```
public class MainApp extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JPanel panel;

private JMenuBar m_menuBar;
private JMenu m_menuSales;

private JMenuItem m_itmSalesNewBuisness;
private JMenuItem m_itmSalesAppointments;

private static MainApp instance = null;

public static MainApp getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new MainApp();
    }

    return instance;
}

private MainApp() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    m_menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    m_menuSales = new JMenu("Sales");
    m_itmSalesAppointments = new JMenuItem("Appointments");
    m_itmSalesAppointments.addActionListener(this);
    m_itmSalesNewBuisness = new JMenuItem("New Business");
    m_itmSalesNewBuisness.addActionListener(this);

    m_menuBar.add(m_menuSales);
    setJMenuBar(m_menuBar);

    setSize(1300, 700);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MainApp();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(m_itmSalesNewBuisness == e.getSource()){
        if(panel != null) {
            remove(panel);
            invalidate();
        }
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        panel = new CopyOfNewBusiness();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        add(panel);
    } else if(m_itmSalesAppointments == e.getSource()){
        if(panel != null) {
            remove(panel);
            invalidate();
        }
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        panel = new AppointmentTracker();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        add(panel);
    }
}

public JDatePickerImpl setDatePicker() {
    UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
    model.setSelected(true);
    JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model);
    JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());
    return datePicker;      
}
```

NewBusiness.java

```
public class CopyOfNewBusiness extends JPanel implements ActionListener, ItemListener {

private JLabel m_lblDate;
private JDatePickerImpl m_dtpDate;

private JLabel m_lblFollowUpDate;
private UtilDateModel followUpDateModel;
private JDatePanelImpl followUpDatePanel;
private JDatePickerImpl m_dtpFollowUp;

public CopyOfNewBusiness() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
    setLayout(null);

    m_lblDate = new JLabel("Date");
    m_lblDate.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 30);
    add(m_lblDate);

    m_dtpDate = MainApp.getInstance().setDatePicker();
    m_dtpDate.setBounds(120, 10, 120, 30);
    add(m_dtpDate);

    m_lblFollowUpDate = new JLabel("Follow Up Date");
    m_lblFollowUpDate.setBounds(10, 370, 100, 30);
    add(m_lblFollowUpDate);

    followUpDateModel = new UtilDateModel();
    followUpDatePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(followUpDateModel);
    m_dtpFollowUp = new JDatePickerImpl(followUpDatePanel);
    m_dtpFollowUp.setBounds(120, 370, 120, 30);
    add(m_dtpFollowUp);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight()));
}
```

}

Comment: Consider having a look at CardLayout and make use if appropriate layout managers...

Comment: try cutting down your code to just the problem you are having. For example all the LookAndFeel stuff is irrelevant. Its just more headache for us.

Comment: Also, beware, a component can only reside within a single container at a time

Comment: @MadProgrammer can't we use Absolute lay out for the same?

Comment: @MadProgrammer
I have tried using card layout, but problem is still the same, datepicker is not visible unless a event is performed.

Comment: @OliverWatkins
I have already reduced the code, Please try to run this code in you workspace, may be you will understand my problem.

PS: I will post more focused code in new answer.

Comment: The problem isn't with `CardLayout`, it's with some other part of your code

Comment: @MadProgrammer
Please try to run this code, and hopefully you will come up with some solution for the problem.

Comment: @Akshat You're code's not complete, so I non can run it, we can just guess

Comment: @all
finally resolved the problem, thanks. Figured what I needed. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933567/add-this-jdatepicker-in-jpanel-instead-jframe-in-java/26046307?noredirect=1#comment40803162_26046307) worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

please import

```
    import java.util.Date; 
    import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePanelImpl;
    import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePickerImpl;
    import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.impl.UtilDateModel;
```

Declaration

```
    JDatePickerImpl datePicker;
```

Adding Datepicker to JPanel

```
      JLabel l22=new JLabel("DATE :");
      l22.setBounds(100,350,100,20);
      p5_assgn_work.add(l22);

      UtilDateModel model=new UtilDateModel();
      JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model);
      datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel);
      datePicker.setBounds(220,350,120,30);
      p5_assgn_work.add(datePicker);
```

To get Date

```
            Date selectedDate = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();
            String date=selectedDate+"";
```

p5_assgnwork is a JPanel

NB: jar file needed for datepicker

Comment: I have already imported the jar and packages, the problem I am facing is datepicker is not displayed until some event is performed.